# $V= \int_{t-\eta}^t \int_s^t f(v,s)\, dv\,ds$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, multiple-integral

I wan t to know how to calculate $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} $ of the following double integral.

$$V= \int_{t-\eta}^t \int_s^t f(v,s)\, dv\,ds$$

Comment: Do you know Leibniz rule?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Use [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), i.e. the one-dimensional differentiation under the integral sign (assuming that $f$ is sufficiently regular), $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{d}
{{dt}}\int\limits_{a\left( t \right)}^{b\left( t \right)} {F(t,s)} ds = F(t,b(t))b'(t)- F(t,a(t))a'(t) 
+ \int_{a ( t)}^{b(t)} F_t(t,s)ds$$
where $F(t,s)=\int_s^t f(v,s) dv$ and therefore $F_t( t,s)=f(t,s)$.

Comment: Great! Thanks to show me this rule, i didn't know about it!!!